# how to solve trigonometric inequalities with interval method when we have even number of equal roots?

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

I was trying to find critical points for:
$$f(x)=-\cos x-\frac{\cos 2x}4+\frac54$$
$f'(x)$ is:
$$f(x)'=\sin x(\cos x+1)$$
then I had to find interval for $f(x)$, where x is $$0<x<2\pi$$
$$$$
$$\sin x=0$$
$$\cos x=-1$$
and both roots equals to
$$x = \pi$$
And here is the question, I was taught that when we get even number of equal roots, we do not change the signs in interval, but oddly here we had to change it, why?
My initial answer was:
$$0 < x < \pi \ \ ∪  \ \ \pi < x < 2\pi$$
but it was:
$$0 < x < \pi $$
which is weird, for other inequalities like
$$\left(\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\cos x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)>0$$
it works well and we do not change the value at point π/6
so the answer is: $$\frac{5\pi}{6} < x < \frac{11\pi}{6}$$

Comment: At the title of your question, you mention “trigonometric inequalities”. Which inequality are you trying to prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin x$ changes sign when crossing $x=\pi$ but $\cos x + 1$ does not since it is tangent to the $x$-axis at $x=\pi$, so their product ends up changing sign. In a sense, $\cos x + 1$ itself has an 'even number' of roots (it is close to the function $(x-\pi)^2/2$ near $\pi$) which is why your method does not work; this can be checked by Taylor expansion near $\pi$. But the method is only rigorous for a polynomial anyway, so I would suggest actually drawing the functions and checking the signs to be sure for such problems.

EDIT: Here is a recap of your method as I understand it. The end goal is to check whether $f'$ changes signs around some point $x=x_0$ satisfying $f'(x_0)=0$, which would imply that $x_0$ is indeed a critical point. If $f$ (and hence $f'$) is a polynomial, this can be done by simply computing the multiplicity of the root $x_0$; $f'$ changes signs if and only if the multiplicity is odd.

To answer @user2661923's question, the method is naively only rigorous for polynomials because multiplicity is only defined for polynomials. However, since the local behavior in question (sign of $f'$) is entirely determined by the leading term in the Taylor expansion, the method also works whenever the expansion exists - just compute derivatives up to the first nonzero term, $f'$ changes signs if and only if the degree is odd. Since trigonometric and most other elementary functions are smooth, the method will in fact still work.

The only case where it fails is when the Taylor series of $f'$ fails to converge to $f'$. For example, suppose
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & x\leq 0 \\ x^3 & x>0\end{cases}.$$
Then is the degree at $x=0$, $2$ or $3$? In such cases, we must manually check the sign of $f'$ around $0$ to see if it changes, which is not at all a bad option in general: for this example (and yours, and many others), simply doodling the graph is much easier than differentiating it multiple times.

Comment: If you have the time, perhaps you could expand your answer.  For example, why is it that "the method is only rigorous for a polynomial"?  Also, is the method rigorous for a (convergent) polynomial of infinite degree, such as a Taylor series?

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you very much, but why does this method works only for polynomials?
And also, does it mean I can not use this method for solving trigonometric equations?

Comment: And why is it not polynomial? T.T it is y = sin(x) + sin(x)cos(x), that is also polynomial, isn't it?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, which is why it works for most practical functions; the only factor is the degree of the leading nonzero term (assuming the Tayler series is convergent). I have added an edit which goes into more detail.